# how to open dynamic link to my app from my app

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I know that use dynamic links to open other app or website generally.

My question is

is it available to open my app with dynamic link from my app?

In Additionally my app is iOS app.

Comment: You want to open your own app with a dynamic link that comes from your own app?

Comment: @jnpdx yes, correct. The dynamic link has url to show in a webview. It works on Android, but not in iOS. In iOS, dynamic link opens webpage has 'open' button to move appstore.

Comment: If you're in a `WKWebView`, why not use the delegate methods to intercept the URL and open it yourself within the app?

Comment: To prevent an infinite loop, URLs that point at your app won't open in your app when opened from your app; They will open in Safari.  The assumption is if you are already in your app you could just move to the correct screen; If you are opening the URL it is assumed to be a URL your app can't handle

Comment: @jnpdx Good suggestion. If open dynamic link from another app, continue userActivity function is called, but not called in my app.

Comment: @Paulw11 thanx for your explanation. is there docs or something about this problem?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46834222/how-can-i-use-universal-links-when-i-call-openurl-inside-my-own-app